# Python + GNU Plot: dealing with missing values

Tags: python, gnuplot

For clarity I have isolated my problem and used a small but complete snippet to describe it.

I have a bunch of data but there is a lot of missing pieces. I want to ignore these (a break in the graph if it were a line graph). I have set "?" to be the symbol for missing data. Here is my snippet:

```
import math
import Gnuplot

gp = Gnuplot.Gnuplot(persist=1)
gp("set datafile missing '?'")

x = range(1000)

y = [math.sin(a) + math.cos(a) + math.tan(a) for a in x]

# Force a piece of missing data
y[4] = '?'

data = Gnuplot.Data(x, y, title='Plotting from Python')
gp.plot(data);

gp.hardcopy(filename="pyplot.png",terminal="png")
```

But it doesn't work:

```
> python missing_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "missing_test.py", line 8, in <module>
    data = Gnuplot.Data(x, y, title='Plotting from Python')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Gnuplot/PlotItems.py", line 560, in Data
    data = utils.float_array(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Gnuplot/utils.py", line 33, in float_array
    return numpy.asarray(m, numpy.float32)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 230, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Gnuplot is calling `numpy.asarray` to convert your Python list into a numpy array.
Unfortunately, this command (with `dtype=numpy.float32`) is incompatible with a Python list that contains strings.

You can reproduce the error like this:

```
In [36]: np.asarray(['?',1.0,2.0],np.float32)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.pyc in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    228 
    229     """
--> 230     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    231 
    232 def asanyarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Furthermore, the [Gnuplot python module (version 1.7) docs](http://dsnra.jpl.nasa.gov/software/Python/python-modules/Gnuplot.html) say

> - There is no provision for missing data points in array data (which
>     gnuplot allows via the 'set missing' command).

I'm not sure if this has been fixed in version 1.8.

How married are you to gnuplot? [Have you tried matplotlib](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Plotting_values_with_masked_arrays)?